# Splitting a String at a certain point/character in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I've seen this question asked a few times but i'm getting back some weird results.

Does `split()` in javascript convert a string into an array?

Basically, `onClick` I `console.log` - `$(this).attr('class')`

I get the classes from my element which is `styled_main selected_origin`. I want to append the second class to another element so I do this : `$(this).attr('class').split("styled_main ")`

However, I get back an array that looks like `["", "selected_origin"]` I'm trying to get back just the string of which should look like : `selected_origin`

Comment: The split removes the character for which you are splitting, so `styled_main ` choosen as a splitter, would remove the `styled_main ` from your result, and give an empty string as the first match (all the rest would then simply be the rest of the text (as I am guessing, your splitter only occures once in your text))

Comment: `Does split() in javascript convert a string into an array?` `split()` returns an array of course

Comment: You can also use `$(this).attr('class').replace("styled_main ", '')`

Comment: @jcubic although it wouldn't make a difference in this case, i would choose the /g option for replace :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split your string by space  and it will return `["styled_main", "selected_origin"]` then get the second column (index 1) like :

```
$(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1];
//OR
$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/)[1];
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
alert( "styled_main selected_origin".split(/\s+/)[1] );
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks, man! Why did that work? Why am I passing through the `[1]`. Also, how come my first attempt didn't work?

Answer (score 4):

You could use instead:

```
this.classList[1]
```

See support for [classList](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)

Comment: Is there any benefit vs `$(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1];` ? why would you use one over the other? For readability?

Comment: @DevJuniorThe50421st If for some reason there is more than one space set between each class, splitting just on one space would fail. At least you should use `.split(/\s+/)` instead of `.split(" ")`.